# Doubling the size of a stack

Tags: scheme, push

I am trying to push! onto a full stack by doubling the vector size and copying the old stack elements into it. However, my code currently runs in an endless loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
(define push!
    (lambda (ra-stack item)
      (if (<= (vector-length (cells ra-stack))
              (height ra-stack))
          (begin (display "Enlarging stack...")
                 (enlarge-stack! ra-stack)
                 (push! ra-stack item))
          (begin (vector-set! (cells ra-stack) (height ra-stack) item) 
                 (set-height! ra-stack (+ (height ra-stack) 1)) ra-stack))))

  (define enlarge-stack!
    (lambda (ra-stack)
      (let ((cells-length (vector-length (cells ra-stack))))
        (make-vector (* 2 cells-length)))))
```

All code below correctly works.

```
(define set-height! 
    (lambda (ra-stack new-height)
      (vector-set! ra-stack 0 new-height)))

(define cells  
    (lambda (ra-stack)
      (vector-ref ra-stack 1)))

(define height
    (lambda (ra-stack)
      (vector-ref ra-stack 0)))

(define set-cells!  
    (lambda (ra-stack new-cells)
      (vector-set! ra-stack 1 new-cells)))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `enlarge-stack!` doesn't affect its argument in any way. It doesn't `set-cells!` its cells to the new enlarged vector; nor does it attempt to copy the elements from the old vector to the new.

What you currently have is more appropriately called `enlarged-stack-cells`. I.e. it returns new, enlarged, empty vector ready to receive the copies of the old values.

```
(define enlarged-stack-cells
    (lambda (ra-stack)
      (let ((cells-length (vector-length (cells ra-stack))))
        (make-vector (* 2 cells-length)))))     ; returns the new vector

(define enlarge-stack!
    (lambda (ra-stack)
      (let ((cs (enlarged-stack-cells ra-stack)))
        (begin
          (copy-cells! cs (cells ra-stack))     ; write it
          (set-cells! ra-stack cs)))))
```

Write it:

```
(define copy-cells!
    (lambda (newcells oldcells)
      (let ((cells-length (vector-length oldcells)))
         ....
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still terribly new to this. To write copy-cells! would I use (vector-copy!)?

Comment: @Ganondalf yes, [`(vector-copy! dest dest-start src)`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector-copy%21) seems like a good choice. With it you won't even need `cells-length`.

Comment: Awesome, I got it! Thank for all of your help!